# compound xpath expressions across nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking at the w3c bookstore xpath example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp).

Based on that xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

    <bookstore>

    <book category="COOKING">
      <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
      <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>30.00</price>
    </book>

    <book category="CHILDREN">
      <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
      <author>J K. Rowling</author>
      <year>2005</year>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>

    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
      <author>James McGovern</author>
      <author>Per Bothner</author>
      <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
      <author>James Linn</author>
      <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>49.99</price>
    </book>

    <book category="WEB">
      <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
      <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
      <year>2003</year>
      <price>39.95</price>
    </book>

</bookstore>
```

I am trying to do this with XPath:

> "Does this XML docuement have a book that has an author 'James
>   McGovern' and a price of '49.99' AND does this XML document also have
>   a book that has an author 'Erik T. Ray' and a price of '39.95'

**That human statement is true, what is the XPath equivalent?
Is it possible to run expressions across sibling nodes, and if so, how?**

To clarify, in other languages, one might do something like this:

```
(author1 = 'James McGovern' and price1 = '49.99') and (author2 = 'Erik T. Ray' and price2 = '39.95')
```

Where author1\price1 are children of:
`<book category="WEB">` with title: `<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>`

And author2\price2 are children of:
`<book category="WEB">` with title: `<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>`

Comment: the `] and [` makes no sense for me. What are you expecting from that?

Comment: I know, this is a hard problem to describe. I've posted an edit to clarify...hopefully.

Comment: I'm sure you mean `or` in this case

Comment: No, I mean `and` but of the cousin book node.

Comment: `(author = 'James McGovern' and price = '49.99') and (author = 'Erik T. Ray' and price = '39.95')` is logically impossible. How should the price for example being `49.99` and `39.95` at the same time?

Comment: Perhaps that is a poor example, the items in the left expression and right expression would be pointing at different book nodes, I just don't know how to express it syntactically, or if it is even possible.

Comment: tell me which nodes you are expecting to be the result. (maybe add this to the question)

Comment: I have made additional edits to clarify.

Comment: Will prepare an example. I'm still sure that you mean `or`.. Note this is boolean language not human language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*:

After your last edit, I finally got what you are trying exactly :). If you want to make sure that both nodes are present, you can use the following query:

```
boolean(/bookstore[book[price = "39.95" and author = "Erik T. Ray"] and book[price = "49.99" and author = "James McGovern"]])
```

Comment: After last edit I understand your question completely. :) I hope my answer is ok for you although it not answers your question directly. It just returns the two nodes if they are present.

Comment: @javamonkey79 Never thought that the `and` can make sense! :)

Comment: @javamonkey79 you were just missing a `book`

Comment: Thanks for your persistence, I figured there had to be a way, but I just couldn't get the syntax right. FWIW, if my title or anything else doesn't make sense please do edit (not that you need my permission for that) :)

Comment: I think it's ok (I'm not a native english speaker, unlikely that I'll do it better ;). However, your last update makes all clear! and makes the question really interesting! Maybe you could put this to the top to make others read this earlier

Answer (score 1):

Performing comparison *for each book* is all that is required so the updated XPath is:

```
boolean(//book[author='James McGovern' and price='49.99']) and boolean(//book[author='Erik T. Ray' and price='39.95'])
```

or if there is adocument with multiple bookstores and you want to find all bookstores with both books you can do:

```
/bookstore[book[author='James McGovern' and price='49.99'] and book[author='Erik T. Ray' and price='39.95']]
```

Comment: No, not quite. I know it is not very clear - I really suck at XPath, sorry. Please see my latest edit. +1 for trying?